# Bulk update through MarkLogic 8 Patch functionality

Tags: marklogic, bulkupdate

Using ML8's Patch functionality I was able to update a document by providing its URI. But if patch is needed on multiple documents, say a new child needs to be added to all XML/JSON documents in a collection, can we do that in ML8 !

Answer (score 1):

At present, [PATCH on /v1/documents](http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/PATCH/v1/documents) only targets one page. For bulk updates, take a look at [Corb2](https://github.com/marklogic/corb2).

Comment: Thanks Dave for the info.. Is there any plan with ML to have this functionality ! Also, for Corb2 are there any prerequisites that I should know beforehand ?

Comment: I'm not aware of any plans to add that functionality. The best thing you can do is pass the request through your official Support contact, so that MarkLogic Product Management knows the customer connection to the request.

Comment: Corb2 works through XDBC rather than REST, but in MarkLogic 8 that can go through the [Enhanced HTTP app server](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/service#id_12021). Corb2 uses Java, so that's the other prerequisite.